# Multiple Accounts

Tags: discussion

Do we have a policy on multiple accounts (for a single user)?  I'm assuming they are banned, since they subvert the SE model.

Obviously one might not know if a single user has multiple accounts, but I couldn't help noticing that Robert Johnson seems to have three accounts with the same name but different reputations.

- https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/15201/robert-johnson
- https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/15214/robert-johnson
- https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/users/15217/robert-johnson

Comment: Links? It's possible to create separate accounts accidentally on sites is there significant usage on both accounts?

Comment: @JamesKingsbery I added the links. The accounts aren't banned, so I think this user is just having some trouble. I left a comment on one of his posts to point him to the 'contact us' link at the bottom of every page, if he has problems logging in. That was before he created his third account. Then again, if he doesn't know how to log in, he may not have seen that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiple accounts aren't against the rules intrinsically (to my knowledge). Some people have separate accounts to ask questions they should know the answer to but are too embarrassed to ask on their main account. This is fine.

It's only bad when you use your multiple accounts to upvote yourself or downvote others multiple times and things like that. The mods have a number of tools to detect when this happens, fortunately.

In Roberts case, looks like those are all unregistered accounts. Nothing we can really do if someone doesn't want to register.